# PHP: Including files in my own MVC framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, include

I've just started to build my very own MVC framework. Feel's kind of nice to know everything from the ground up and only get the stuff that's really necessary for my app.

I come from a codeIgniter background which helped me to get into the MVC perspective of seeing things. In codeigniter, to include a file, [codeIgniters very own load class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) is used.

This load class, when loading a file, checks if a file have previously been included, and if not includes it, which ensures that a file isn't included twice.

However this method of including files has the downside of making it impossible (?) to run tests on my files or take advantage of PHPdoc in my IDE, which I need.

Clearly, I can use the normal `include` & `require` functions in PHP forwards and backwards across my application, where a certain library would be needed, but it clearly won´t be good to possible include the same file twice...

**So - what's a good solution to use in my own PHP5 MVC framework to include files?**

Comment: I am slightly worried about writing redundant code to cover possible dependencies, when using a library, for instance, in different controllers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing a similar thing to you, and I'm using [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Just put this in index.php:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}
```

or include whatever logic you need to check multiple directories.

**Edit:** Here's my (slightly flaky) code for checking an alternate path. It could be done a lot more cleanly if you were going to need to check multiple paths.

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
  $path = INC_PATH . strtolower($class_name) . '.php';

  if (!file_exists($path)) {
    $path = MODELS_PATH . strtolower($class_name) . '.php';
  }

  require $path;
}
```

Comment: Would you like to tell me your solution to handle multiple directories?

Answer (score 2):

just use `include_once` and `require_once` . while CI has a load class, you're by no means required to use it.

Answer (score 2):

use include_once/ require_once but the best solution would be working with a autoloader

http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.autoload.php

what IDE do you use?

Comment: Eclipse PHP is my choice of IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Generally php has the built in `include_once` which as the name says includes the file, but only once.

Or you can use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) which most IDEs support (though some need a bit of a hint - depends on what IDE are you using).